# Missing Node while Printing a Sorted List (C)

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, null

I have a linked list that is being sorted alphabetically; however, when printing the list I seem to be missing a node in the output, I believe what is happening is that one of the nodes is being set to NULL while being swapped.

```
int compare_by_lastname(node_t *a, node_t *b)       // these two functions
    { return strcmp(a->lastName, b->lastName); }    // compare two nodes
int compare_by_firstname(node_t *a, node_t *b)
    { return strcmp(a->firstName, b->firstName); }

void swapNode(node_t* a, node_t* b)     // helper function for sortList()
{
    node_t temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void sortList(node_t **head, int (*comp)(node_t*, node_t*))    // sorting using function pointer
{
    node_t *temp1 = NULL;
    node_t *temp2 = NULL;
    int swapped = 0;

    if (*head == NULL) 
        { return; }

    do 
    {
        swapped = 0;
        temp1 = *head;
        while (temp1->next != temp2) 
        {
            if (comp(temp1, temp1->next) > 0)
            {
                swapNode(temp1, temp1->next);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        }
        temp2 = temp1;
    } while (swapped);
}
```

Here is the block of code that prints my list

```
    while (temp != NULL)    // node_t* temp = head
    {
        // if provided day of the month is invalid, skip to the next node
        if (checkInvalidDate(temp) == true)
            { temp = temp->next; }

        fprintf(out, "Name:\t%s %s\n", temp->firstName, temp->lastName);
        fprintf(out, "Date of Birth:\t%s %s, %s\n", temp->bd.month, 
                                                    temp->bd.day, 
                                                    temp->bd.year);
        fprintf(out, "Major:\t%s\n", temp->major);
        fprintf(out, "Year:\t%s\n\n", temp->classStanding);
        temp = temp->next;      // next element
    }
```

Additionally, here is the file that the code reads from to create the list.

```
Nininger,Noah,July,31,2002,CS/BS,Junior
Doe,Jane,December,12,2003,CS/BS,Sophomore
Doe,John,December,12,2003,CS/BS,Sophomore
Joe,Average,February,3,2002,CS/BS,Freshman
```

The sorting functions do appear to be sorting the list as needed, but I think one of the nodes is NULL since the issue only appeared after the implementation of `sortList()`

Comment: You shouldn't swap the entire node, just the data. Otherwise the `next` links will not be correct.

Comment: Counterpoint: you shouldn't swap nodes at all, just manipulate the links.

Comment: Note: Insertion Sort is even easier to write than Bubble Sort for linked lists, and it's faster, too, for most data.